# CSS transition only activates when class is toggled on, not off

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have an issue with a transition effect I have on multiple elements on a page. I am attempting to create a sliding side menu for my responsive top navigation menu where the relative body and a fixed header bar positions to the right when the navigation toggle link is clicked.

The transition of position right from 0 to 200px works as intended when opening the navigation menu but when it comes to closing it, the blue header bar returns immediately to `right: 0px`, but the transition on the red main content works as normal. You can see the word 'nav' move instantly before the rest of the content in red transitions. This isn't as noticeable in the fiddle but on the actual site I'm building it's very noticeable.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aethyrion/e0zzxwbg/8/) of the below:

```js
 $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
   $('body, .header-bar').toggleClass('menu-open');
   return false;
 });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #c00;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu-toggle {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
.header-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #00c;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
.menu {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.menu-open {
  right: 200px;
}
.menu-open .menu-side {
  right: 0;
}
.menu-side {
  background-color: #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu,
.menu-open,
.menu-side {
  -webkit-transition: right 0.2s ease;
}
.logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-side ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0
}
.menu-side ul li a {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-side ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-bar">
    <div class="logo">MWP</div>

    <div class="menu-toggle">Nav</div>

    <nav class="menu-side">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#my-work">My Work</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- omitted content filler was here - found in jFiddle -->
</header>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

I've been over my CSS many times and checked the jQuery is adding/removing the classes needed and I can't see what I've done wrong. I need the blue bar to remain in a fixed position.

Comment: Place the transition on `.header-bar` instead. The transition wont play on the way out, because it is applied to the class that is being removed.

Comment: I could actually kiss you!! lol! Worked a treat and makes perfect sense to apply the transition to `.header-bar`. Thanks so much!

Comment: I will create an answer :) though this is a pretty common issue.

Comment: @misterManSam is there any way to accredit your answer? +1 it or something?

Comment: I made an answer that you can accept by clicking the green checkmark (if you wish, it's not mandatory)

Comment: Accepted your answer but unfortunately, I don't have a high enough reputation on here to upvote your answer :/ Thanks again

Comment: If you keep participating well, then you will earn the privilege :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the transition on `.header-bar`. Currently the transition wont play on the way out, because it is applied to the class that is being removed. It will look something like this:

```
.menu,
.header-side,
.header-bar,
.menu-side{
  transition: right 0.2s ease;
}
```

If you wanted to apply a different transition on the way in, then you would apply the transition to `.menu-open` *as well*. For example, this snippet would provide a slower transition on the way in and a fast transition on the way out:

```
.header-bar {
  transition: right 0.2s ease;
}

.menu-open {
  transition: right 0.5s ease;
}
```

### Full Example

Note the use of the unprefixed transition. [The `-webkit-` prefix is possibly required for older browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) Add the prefixed property above the un-prefixed property.

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('body, .header-bar').toggleClass('menu-open');
  return false;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #c00;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu-toggle {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
.header-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #00c;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
.menu {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.menu-open {
  right: 200px;
}
.menu-open .menu-side {
  right: 0;
}
.menu-side {
  background-color: #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu,
.menu-open,
.header-side,
.header-bar,
.menu-side{
  transition: right 0.2s ease;
}
.logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-side ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0
}
.menu-side ul li a {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-side ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-bar">
    <div class="logo">MWP</div>

    <div class="menu-toggle">Nav</div>

    <nav class="menu-side">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#my-work">My Work</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- omitted content filler was here - found in jFiddle -->
</header>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note the second snippet I added in my answer. If you wanted, you could add a slightly different transition on the way in and out :)